# Dynamics CRM 2013 throws SQL Timeout adding a user to a team

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a simple but tough problem.

I am trying to add an user to a team through user interface, however I'm getting SQL Time Out for some users.

I got no plugins firing on association request. I also did not find any familiarity between the ones I am getting this error.

I have even turned the trace log on which did not give me much more details.

Following the error log generated by tracing tool.

```
Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: {D3DE2F15-53FA-4A12-A286-346CC4BFD310}; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: Associate; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: SQL timeout expired.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ManyToManyForwardEntityAssociationCommand.AssociateEntities(EntityReference entity1, EntityReference entity2, String relationshipName, Boolean associate, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ManyToManyForwardEntityAssociationCommand.Execute(RelationshipProcessor processor, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, Guid entityId, EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities, Boolean associate, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.RelationshipProcessor.ProcessAssociation(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, Guid entityId, Relationship relationship, EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities, Boolean associate, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.RelationshipProcessor.Associate(EntityReference entityReference, Relationship relationship, EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities, ExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: SQL timeout expired.
Inner Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.BusinessManagementUtility.LockSystemUserEntriesForTeamMembershipChange(Guid userId, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TeamMembershipServiceInternal`1.Associate(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.HandleAssociationOperation(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, Boolean createAssociation, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.AssociateEntities(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
```

Comment: Is it a consistent behavior (i.e. one user always times out, another user never does) ? Also, is it 2011 or 2013 ?

Comment: This is where your error occurs: `at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.BusinessManagementUtility.LockSystemUserEntriesForTeamMembershipChange(Guid userId, ExecutionContext context)`. How many records are in the POA table? Does the same error also occur on other users and/or teams?

Comment: It's CRM 2013, The error occurs sporadic for some users.

Comment: Is it happening when there is a high volume of transactions?  I have seen SQL transactions just go into a waiting status (permanently) when SQL can't handle the load before.  When you say its sporadic for some users - does that mean that the same user always times out when adding to the same team, but its only certain users?  or that User A cant be added to Team B today, but its no problem tomorrow?

Comment: Well, I got it working now, I was trying to add a user to a team by using AssociateRequest, I've just changed to AddMember and got it working!